# Variable in function won't be reassigned

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i'm new to Pinescript. Can sb tell me, why the float var tempHigh in the function "highestClose" won't be reassigned?
I already read https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#id4 however this does not help me. I also checked the doku on the if statment.

Code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Upper Lower Sup", overlay=true)
highestClose(num) =>
    float tempHigh = 0.0
    for i = (last_bar_index - num) to last_bar_index
        if(close[i] > tempHigh)
            tempHigh := close[i]                    // <-- Here it should reassign if condition is true
    tempHigh

num = input(50, "Bars in the past")
float highpoint = highestClose(num)
var higestPriceLine= line.new((last_bar_index - num), highpoint, last_bar_index + 20, highpoint, xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.none)
```

Thanks^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reassignment logic is correct (although I'm not too sure on what you're trying to accomplish there, so there might be other issues), its your method of outputting the result (`line.new()`) is wrong.

You create the line with the `var` keyword, which means that it is created on the first bar (bar_index == 0) and left untouched after that. On the first bar, the `highpoint` is always 0.0 with the way you wrote the script. Let's say your chart has 2000 bars, and so the `last_bar_index` is 1999 -- `close[i]` in your loop will refer to values in range from `close[1949]` to `close[1999]`. On the first bar, none of these values exist (`na` will be returned), so the `if close[i] > tempHigh` condition will always be false. Thus, the line created on bar 0 will be created with `y = 0` and will not be changed after that. Even after `highpoint` is reassigned, the line will not reflect it, because there is no directive from the script to change the line.

The easier (in this case) way to visualise the value of the line is to add the `plot(highpoint)` to the end of the script. `plot()` takes the value of the variable on each bar and outputs it on the chart. If you do so, you'll see that on the last 50 bars, `highpoint` actually changes from 0 to a different value.

Another thing to note is that, from what I can gather, you approach the task incorrectly. If your goals is to output the high of the last 50 bars on the chart, the `for i = (last_bar_index - num) to last_bar_index` is not the way to go. In this implementation, you access bars waaaay back in the past, because `close[1950]` is not the close of the bar 1950, but the close of the bar 1950 bars back from the one where the script is calculated.

A more fitting way would be to only execute the logic on the last bar, cycle through the last 50 bars there, reassign the values and modify the line:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
barsBack = input(50)
var highestClose = 0.0
var line1 = line.new(na, na, na, na) // a dummy line created on the first bar, we'll move it to proper coordinates later
if barstate.islast
    for i = barsBack - 1 to 0
        highestClose := math.max(close[i], highestClose)
    line.set_xy1(line1, bar_index[barsBack], highestClose)
    line.set_xy2(line1, bar_index, highestClose)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the assignment of the variable

Your problem is your approach.. last_bar_index is a count for the bars that are in your chart. you can try to `plot(close[last_bar_index])`, which shouldn't work depending on what symbol you are.

my recommondation is that you use the `ta.highest()` function of tradingview

`tempHigh = ta.highest(close, lenght) //will print the highest close of the length`

if you want to do it your way, with a for loop, you can use the example of the other comment